# how to post default thumbnail if post not created yet

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I want to show a default thumbnail if a custom post not created yet.
Here is my loop:

```
<?php  while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<?php  
   if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
       the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'mySlides' ) ); 
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="dummy-image-1-1.jpg" class="mySlides" height="350px"/>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php
       endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata(); 

    ?>
```

If I created a post but not posted a thumbnail then show default thumbnail. But If I didn't create a post yet I want to show a default thumbnail. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. "If I didn't create a post" -> if you didn't create a post, then there is nothing in the loop. How do you know whether something wasn't created yet?

Comment: I already told it in my question. If I created a post but not upload image then it shows default image like `echo` `else` But If I didn't created a post I want to show a default default Like if post not exists yet then show default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Create "images" folder in current active theme the put "dummy-image-1-1.jpg" in that folder.**

```
<?php  
if ($the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'mySlides' ) ); 
        } else {
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/dummy-image-1-1.jpg'; ?>" class="mySlides" height="350px"/>
        <?php
        }
    endwhile;
else:
?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/dummy-image-1-1.jpg'; ?>" class="mySlides" height="350px"/>
<?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

> Use path according to the theme(parent or child)

- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri): url path to current Theme directory
- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/): url path to parent Theme directory

Comment: brother my question is  If I created a post but not upload image then it shows default image like echo else But If I didn't created a post I want to show a default default Like if post not exists yet then show default

Comment: I already get the image so it doesn't matter just want to show if post to exists yet.

Comment: @Sabbir I have updated code...Try it please...

Comment: It works and I got it. Actually, I forgot the method Thanks @Tanmay